# sql server 2008 limit on exec statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just needed to double check if there is a limit of characters on EXEC command in t-sql?
If I have a variable with varchar(max) and execute the command using EXEC, you reckon that would be ok?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be fine, according to [this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

The relevant part:

> **Using EXECUTE with a Character String**
>
> In earlier versions of SQL Server, character strings are limited to 8,000 bytes. This requires concatenating large strings for dynamic execution. **In SQL Server, the varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types can be specified that allow for character strings to be up to 2 gigabytes of data.**