# SQL Exec can't execute long strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec, dynamic-sql

This is my code

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql = 'WITH CTE AS
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @order + ' ' + @Desc + ') AS  RowNum 

    from (SELECT     ID, Subject from a 
    WHERE     (Subject LIKE N''%'' + @searchText + N''%'')) 
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum  BETWEEN (@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize + 1
            AND @pageIndex * @pageSize ;';
```

where @order = "ID" and @pageIndex = 1 and @pageSize = 5 and @searchText = 'a' and @Desc = 'DESC'

I wrote

```
select @sql
```

to see if @sql is executable. I copied it and pasted it and ran it. it worked.
then I wrote

```
exec @sql
```

error! it seems exec just tried to execute some characters from the first of @sql. Is there any limitations on @sql?

p.s: The error is like this

> The name '.........someth' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: SQL does have a limit for this. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910763/sql-server-2008-limit-on-exec-statement

Comment: @marc_s : DECLARE @ sql nvarchar(4000)

Comment: @Aishvarya : If there is no limitation so what's wrong here? I will copy the error message

Comment: The name '.........someth' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @marc_s : as I said I copied and pasted @ sql and it was executed without any error. so there is nothing wrong with it. It is a big complicated query.

Comment: Have you tried `EXEC (@SQL)` (with parens around the `@SQL`) or using `EXEC sp_executeSql @SQL` ? Any difference? Also: if you're using `NVARCHAR`, you should use a `N` prefix when assigning: `SET @SQL = N'.....'` to be consistent

Comment: @marc_s : I updated the question with a simplified version of real query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

**DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = '.............something executable.................';**

This error may occurred due to length of the string exceed more than 4000 characters